# How to create a user with a particular user_id?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, sqlplus

Is it possible to specify the user_id of a user while creating it?

```
SQL> create user user1 identified by user1;

User created.

SQL> select user_id, username from all_users where username='USER1';

   USER_ID USERNAME
---------- ------------------------------
        72 USER1

SQL>
```

Instead of 72, can it be a number that I specify?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not in a supported fashion, no.

Why would you care what the `USER_ID` of a new user was?  That would seem to raise a pile of red flags in my mind.

Comment: Even dropping a user that currently has the desired `USER_ID` does not cause new user creation to use that number.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to migrate logins and users from a server to another there should be another way then forcing their ids and names.

In SQL Server for example there is a system stored procedure (sp_help_revlogin) that generates the necessary scripts to migrate users between servers. I don't know for Oracle, but I'm sure someone has met the problem before.